# Can you heat something in AL foil using IR?

Tags: radiation

Is it possible to heat up, let's  say, a blob of mud, golf ball size, covered in AL foil, with IR? Also, how efficient would that be? 
Is there an IR wavelength that would get absorbed far better than the rest?

Comment: Foil is pretty reflective in IR.  For example, most ovens heat mostly with IR and if you wrap something in foil it gets hot a lot slower.

Comment: Yes, but is there a wavelength that is it's sweetspot? Let's say you use just that and it gets mostly absorbed?

Comment: @RickPH If you didn't already notice, Aluminium is a metal. A metal reflects most EM radiation frequencies well because of the wide conduction band they support. In short, THERE IS NO SWEET SPOT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to heat up, let's say, a blob of mud, golf ball size, covered in AL foil, with IR?

Possible? Sure.

> Also, how efficient would that be?

Metals are weakly coupled to the electromagnetic field, i.e. they reflect most of what hits them, at and above visible wavelengths.
That means that most of the incoming radiation just bounces off, so the heating in your case will be pretty inefficient.

> Is there an IR wavelength that would get absorbed far better than the rest?

Let's check.
Here's some data from Wikipedia's article on [reflectivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflectivity):

[image]

The infrared range starts at a wavelength of around 700 nanometers and goes on to all longer wavelengths (i.e. to the right on the plot).
You can see a marked dip in reflectance of aluminum (Al) at ~800 nm to 900 nm which suggests that heating your insulated object would work best at the lowest infrared wavelengths.

Even with the dip, the actual value of the reflectivity of Al is pretty darn high across the board for IR, which is why wrapping things in aluminum foil helps them keep their temperature (cold things stay cold and hot things stay hot).

Comment: In fact Aluminium foil is often used to do the opposite of what you are asking OP.